# Browsers are requesting twice on load

Tags: node.js, express

I have a script that plays music and because of the nature of the script it seems to be running 2 connections for every 1 listener.

What that means is it is creating 2 documents inside Mongodb.

I am wondering is there a way to tell mongoose to not insert document within 5 seconds if the insert has already ran?

I have run a `console.log(req.url)`
and I get the following

```
/dance?uuid=6f70c645-4ef4-4042-854d-a6e87b61e45f

/dance?uuid=6f70c645-4ef4-4042-854d-a6e87b61e45f
```

Which means it is requesting the file twice on load.
Is there away to only allow 1 request to go through and discard the other?

I have tried

```
router.get('/:stationname', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.url)
});
```

Also tried the following

```
var doCSUpdateAlreadyCalled = false;
router.get('/:stationname', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!doCSUpdateAlreadyCalled) {
    doCSUpdateAlreadyCalled = true
    console.log(req.url)
  }
});
```

But it still runs twice.

Comment: We would have to see how the client is working for this request and why two requests are generated.  This should be fixed in the client-side.  You can "debounce" client requests, but much better to fix this particular issue in the client and not cause the problem in the first place.

Comment: Also, the `router.get('/:stationname', ...)` request handler you show doesn't send any response which leads to problems in the client.

Comment: I'm also wondering why you're creating mongodb documents on a GET request.  That is not adhering to the REST guidelines.  A GET should be retrieving a resource, not creating one.

Comment: @jfriend00 because we are logging when a user requests a podcast file.

Comment: Well, you're logging correctly.  You are apparently getting two requests.  Fix the problem in the client implementation.  If you really wanted to do extra DB requests, you could do a query before logging that tests to see if the same music file was recently requested within xx seconds from now, and if so, not log it.  But, really the problem is in the client.  You don't want this extra load on your server.

Comment: @jfriend00 that is basically what I am trying to do, the problem only happens with web browsers and not when users use a media player - Maybe I should be asking how to check if mongodb has updated recently like within 5 seconds.